# Passing multiple types of related variables(Java)

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, sockets, variables

Im developing an app that can connect to a few computers on the local network and sends instructions to them such as: "run this script", "run that script" and blocks new connections to it until they finished running the scripts.

In short I create a thread for each connection, and I need pass to them the port, IP, instruction, duration, thread name. Then the thread creates the socket and passes on through the stream instruction and the duration. The computer on the other side then acknowledges that it received the instruction and that it executed the script. Then the program should block any tries to create a connection with that IP address until the client answers that he finished running the script but will allow connections to unconnected computers. The thread then closes the streams, socket and itself and allows new connections to that computer through new threads.

Now my problem is that I dont know how to create a system that can be scaled eg. add new computers to the system, scripts and duration values.

I tried something like this:

```
        object[0][0] = 2222;                  //PORT
        object[0][1] = "localhost";
        object[0][2] = " to computer1";

        object[1][0] = 2223;
        object[1][1] = "192.168.1.113";
        object[1][2] = " to computer2";

        object[2][0] = 2224;
        object[2][1] = "192.168.1.108";
        object[2][2] = " to computer3";
```

But I cant figure out a way to iterate through that if I want to  send instructions to computer1 and computer3 either the same or different instructions.

Comment: Have you considered classes? Arrays of objects are quite clumsy, and Java *is* object oriented after all.

Comment: You're doing threading, but keeping data in a 2D array instead of a real object. Did you skip the basics of Java?

Comment: I literally forgot about classes, thanks.

Comment: Encapsulate the data about a "Task" - ip, port and payload into a Class ( POJO ). Make the Class implement the "runnable" interface, and implement the run() method which opens up a socket, sends the instruction, waits for the reply and puts the result into the Task object when finished. Then look at the class java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService which can help you run any given Task just by calling it's "submit(Runnable)" method after instantiating the ExecutorService. Then you will need to manage which Tasks are sent to the Executor. A bit advanced but fairly standard java stuff.

Comment: That seems much cleaner than what I was doing.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As [pjklauser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/458965/pjklauser) said, you can start from simple POJO class Config for example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Config{

private String host;
private int port;
private String payload;

public Config(String host, int port, String payload){
    this.host = host;
    this.port = port;
    this.payload = payload;
}

public String getHost() {
    return host;
}

public void setHost(String host) {
    this.host = host;
}

public int getPort() {
    return port;
}

public void setPort(int port) {
    this.port = port;
}

public String getPayload() {
    return payload;
}

public void setPayload(String payload) {
    this.payload = payload;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return this.host + " " + this.port + " " + this.payload;
}

 public static void main(String []args){
     ArrayList<Config> configs = new ArrayList<Config>();
     Config c1 = new Config("localhost", 2222, "To computer1");
     Config c2 = new Config("localhost", 2223, "To computer2");

     configs.add(c1);
     configs.add(c2);

     for (Config c: configs){
         System.out.println(c.toString());
     }
 }
}
```

I hope this will help!